# Why to upload files to django static directory instead of directly to django static root

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks, django-staticfiles, django-1.8

I would like to know the following:

1)Why should you upload files into static directories and run 'collectstatic' instead of directly uploading to the static root folder.I know it sounds little bit insecure , not getting the files run through the python first but still..

2)What does it do to the static files when you run a 'collectstatic' command

3)What can be consequences of directly uploading to static root and alternative to this , this is not just limited to django framework but to whole web dev community if they have the same workflow to upload all the staticfiles.

Comment: Do you mean static files belonging to your site (its .css files, etc) or files uploaded by a user?

Answer (score 2):

> Why should you upload files into static directories and run
>   'collectstatic'

If you're talking about user submitted content, you should definitly **not** upload it into any static directory - that's what "MEDIA_ROOT" and "MEDIA_URL" are for. "static" files are your app's or project's assets (stylesheets, js etc), which you keep under version control.

As to why you don't directly put those static files in the "static root":

- first because you want to keep those files under version control (they are part of your sources) but serve them directly from the front web server or even eventually from a distinct server, cdn or whatesoever, so you cannot serve them directly from your project's tree, they have to live somewhere the frontserver (or whatever) can serve them.
- also because you want to get *all* those static files - your project's specific ones, but also any static file coming from a 3rd part app you are using.

Which answers your second question: `collectstatic` will, mainly, look for all or your static files (according to your settings) and copy them to the STATIC_ROOT. It may also apply additionnal processing depending on your staticfiles storage.

Note that [all this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/) is [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) FWIW